# How to enable Accessibility on Android 6.0 emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I need to test Accessibility function on Nexus 5 , target Android 6.0 emulator.
could anyone know how to turn on the accessibility function?

Answer (score 3):

First, go to the setting and check if you have talkback.
If you don't have talkback, then you have to download the talkback apk and install in the emulator from the following [link](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/talkback/talkback-4-2-0-release/talkback-4-2-0-3-android-apk-download/)

There are two ways to install the apk in the emulator

1. By simple drag and drop in the apk in the open emulator or
2. By using adb install command.